# Issue with scope inside function/method

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far I've had almost no issues with scope in my project, however the one big exception is de-pickling files.

```
f = open("save_file.dat", "rb+")
Plr = pickle.load(f)[0]
f.close()
```

^ This code works just fine. However if I try to do the de-pickling inside a function, it seems to turn local.

```
def load():
    f = open("save_file.dat", "rb+")
    Plr = pickle.load(f)[0]
    f.close()
```

So I decided to try and make it a method.

```
def load(self):
    ...

    f = open("save_file.dat", "rb+")
    self = pickle.load(f)[0]
    f.close()
```

Usually  when I try to use methods, self refers to the instance of the class, and it changes it's value, but here it seems to once again, be local.

**EDIT** it seems I was being dumb for trying to return the function inside another function, which was not the main one.
Here's something that works:

```
def load():
    f = open("save_file.dat", "rb+")
    return pickle.load(f)[0]
```

And then after that you can change the variable you need to like this:

```
Plr = load()
```

Comment: ...have you heard of `return` yet? It sounds like you need to go through a Python tutorial.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the issue here has anything to do with pickling at all.

Comment: I guess the issue might've been with me being dumb with where i returned the function, as I once again put it inside another function. I'll try it out again

Comment: Anything defined inside a function has local scope. This isn't unique to `pickle`. Also, there's nothing special about `self`. It's just a naming convention for the first argument of instance methods.